# Symfony 2.1 @Template annotation throws 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, templates, annotations, symfony-2.1

I am working on a new project on the most recent version of Symfony 2.1.4, with PHP 5.4.7.

I went through the readme file, passed the `app/check.php` and the configuration, the Acme Demo is running fine, every pages tested.

Then, I added my own bundle, edited the `app/AppKernl.php`, and the `app/routing.yml` so it loads my own `routing.yml` from my bundle, and tested the `indexAction()` in my `SetupController` with

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Setup:index.html.twig');
```

The page is displayed as expected.

Then I changed it to use annotation, so the Controller file became

```
// ...
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

// ...

class SetupController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_setup")
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexAction(){
        // This method is totally empty.

        // Uncommenting the following line actually works, but I want to stick with
        // annotations if possible

        // return $this->render('MyBundle:Setup:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And the routing file became

```
_setup:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/SetupController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

Now the page throws a 500 Internal Server Error (LogicException), with the following message:

```
The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?
```

I tried adding the `$this->render('...')` line to the `indexAction()`, the page renders, but without it just this 500 error.

The Acme Demo is still running beautifully. I tried using `@Template('MyBundle:Setup:index.html.twig')` and `@Template()`, instead of `@Template`, the same error still occurs. The template file is placed in a correct location as the `$this->render()` method found it without problems.

I checked and made sure I didn't turn off annotation in any config files. I also tried clearing the caches, both dev and prod ones, but still no luck.

I can use `$this->render()` as a work around, but I wanted to know what's wrong with the annotation that Symfony won't let me use it.

Thanks in advance for any help or advise! Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `@Template` annotation you need to return an `array()` of variables that will be passed to the template.

If you have no variables than just `return array()`

Comment: Thanks! It worked! In fact I tried this already but it didn't work, I think I must have forgotten to clear the caches before testing. Now everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You should always return a `Response` - thing that `$this - render( someTemplate )` actually does. If you don't want to return anything:

```
return new Response;
```

and symfony will be happy.

[`Response` lays in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation` package for your knowledge.]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I am following the usage of annotation from [Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html), and I don't see that they return a Response object. As far as I can tell, when we use the @Template annotation, the returning array is the parameters passed into the template, instead of a HTTP Response. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Well it may depend on the body of your controller action, or on the missing of the template file for it [I don't remember the convention for default template files right now] - please post the full method just in case!

Comment: Actually the body of the indexAction() is empty, just like the last three examples in the Symfony's documentation.

Comment: I edited the code to provide more details on the Controller file, thanks for the advise!